# WordPress REST API in Integromat: How to overcome “Sorry, you are not allowed to list users / edit this…”

Tags: rest-api, api, wp-api

I am attempting to connect Integromat to my WordPress install.

I have successfully [enabled visibility of custom post types in Integromat by registering my custom post types with `show_in_rest`](https://www.integromat.com/en/requests/requests-to-update-existing-apps/p/wordpress-custom-post-types). (And, though I have also used `show_in_rest` for my custom taxonomies, there seems no way to surface these in Integromat, but that's not the question).

However, in the Integromat dropdowns for the following, I see these REST API permissions errors:

- Categories: Sorry, you are not allowed to edit terms in this taxonomy
- Tags: Sorry, you are not allowed to edit terms in this taxonomy
- Author Sorry, you are not allowed to list users

This is strange to me. I have provably forced custom post types and taxonomies to be seen by Integromat by using `show_in_rest` (and I had to deactive my Disable REST API plugin - what is preventing Integromat from getting a list of out-of-the-box Categories/Tags and Users?

Is there some equivalent `show_in_rest` setting that applies to these, too?

Any solution that requires things like passing different authentication headers may be irrelevant for me, as Integromat wouldn't support that, it's supposed to hide that from me. Doesn't mean Integromat may not have a fix to make. But, ideally, any solution is on my own WordPress install.

Comment: First can you check in the core WP REST API if you see the endpoints? If they're visible there but not in your 3rd party app, this would be a question for their support forums rather than here.

Comment: That's a good point. `wp-json/wp/v2/users`, `wp-json/wp/v2/categories` and `wp-json/wp/v2/tags` all show listings when accessed via the web.

Comment: Ok, so you can list them - but the plugin is complaining about edit. Did you check these permissions as well? Anyway, sounds like it is better fit for Integromat support forums

Comment: Yes, agree. The problem is occurring when Integromat tries to populate dropdowns with Categories, Tags and Authors (corresponding to List actions). There may well be an edit issue, too. But I agree - one for Integromat.